sort objects of a array by a property whithout collections
I have a array of students. My student class has an integer property named score and I want to sort them by their scores. I don't want to use collections.
I used this but it didn't worked:
class sortByScore implements Comparator<Student> {
    public int compare(Student a, Student b)
    {
        return a.score - b.score;
    }
}

I get this error:
Screenshot of the error

Why are you using all that Integer.valueOf and compareTo instead of just Integer.compare(s1.getScore(), s2.getScore())?

What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Telling us what went wrong is part of writing a good question. It will also help if you could share a minimal reproducible example.

I'm sorry this is my first time I have edited my question

Images of text are not well received here. The error message and stack trace should be in the question body as text, not as an image. Use text copy-and-paste to ensure accuracy.

However, these might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it   and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Arrays.sort(a, Comparator.com    paringInt(Student::getScore));

As an aside, doing  return a.score - b.score;  is a bad habit to get into.  Either use a built-in Comparator or take the time to do return a.score < b.score ? -1 : a.score > b.score  ? 1 : 0;

Third option, use Integer.compare(…, …)

It would be helpful if you included the code where you call the sortByScore.compare(Student a, Student b) function.
Your compare function seems fine, but 1 or more items on your array must be null check that first.

One of your student objects is null. Your comparator doesn't support that.
The easiest fix, combined with what's already in the comments, is to wrap your comparator into a null-safe comparator. There are two options:

null students come before non-null students: Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getScore))

null students come after non-null students: Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getScore))


Then there's of course the option to actually prevent null students in your collection or array.
